# How to access Curity SCIM attributes when SCIM account manager is used as Claims value provider

Tags: curity

We are using Curity Community 8.4.1 with SCIM as account-manager using the default datasource. The configuration has been created in Curity 6.x in 2021 and enriched since, but saved and restored during each upgrade process since.

When creating a new claim and selecting **account-manager-claim-provider** as the selected Claim Provider, then if I open the selected attributes form, most of SCIM 2.0 fields are suggested in the combo list. But if I select userName for example, or most of the others fields, testing the claim result in an empty object.
*Note that we have some users in the DB with the tested fields in the accounts table of Curity DB. And no warning when testing the claim*

- It work for *email* but it isn't a field coming from **attributes** column of the accounts table.
- It doesn't work for *userName* (nor username) even if it's also a field outside attributes column
- It work for *name* when configured in Selected attributes without transformation, but doen't know where the value is taken from as this property is an object of the attributes column and not available in the accounts table.
- It doesn't work for other fields of the SCIM schema suggested in 'Selected attributes'
- It doesn't work when typing 'attributes' in 'Selected attributes'

The attributes query has been changed to :

```
SELECT accounts.* FROM accounts WHERE accounts.username = :subject
```

If I switch to the default data source as the Claims provider, then when 'attributes' is configured as Selected Attributes, we see the JSON contained in this field in the DB and we can parse & use it in a transformation. The Claim test work with JSON in 'Before transformation' and object with properties in 'After Transformation'

So the questions are the following :

- **Can Curity SCIM account-manager be used as **account-manager-claim-provider**, and if so what is the right way to feed attributes parameter used in transformation ?**
- **If default datasource must be use instead of account-manager, is there any way to avoid parsing the JSON contains in the attributes column of accounts table for each claim ?**
- Bonus question, **is ES6 be supported in transformation** as using optional chaining, or Array.prototype.map() in transformation make the configuration validation failed and we can commit the updated config.

At the moment we use the default DS, parse the attributes field then set all claims through transformation in a nested object to avoid parsing the JSON for each individual claim based on SCIM attributes. But it seems to be a very dirty way.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Curity Identity Server models its attribute storage for user accounts on the SCIM core schema from [RFC6743](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/inline-errata/rfc7643.html). Custom attributes are stored in an attributes JSON field in order to support any unknown attribute that may be needed, and to avoid adding complexity to database upgrades.

**CLAIMS PROVIDERS**

To understand claims issuing differences, configure 3 claims providers like this. You can do this with a community license. The SCIM claims provider should not have the `Map Account to OpenID Connect Claims` option selected.

[image]

**ISSUING OIDC BUILT-IN CLAIMS**

Use the `account-manager-claims-provider` to issue these, which does some convenience mapping for you. When testing, make sure the scope you select (`profile` in this case) contains the claim:

[image]

**ISSUING SCIM CLAIMS**

When issuing claims based on the SCIM schema, use an account manager claims provider with the `Map Account to OpenID Connect Claims` option deselected. An example for the SCIM roles field is shown here, which I added to a `read` scope. The result shown is already a JSON object and you do not call `JSON.parse` in any transformations:

[image]

You can issue just the primary role value as the claim like this:

```js
function transform(attributes) {
  
  var result = '';
  attributes["roles"].forEach(function(role) {
    if (role.primary) {
      result = role.value;
    }
  });
  
  return result;
}
```

Other SCIM fields, like `userName`, `userType` and `externalId` can be selected in the same way as roles. When using them, ensure that you specify the exact case under `Selected Attributes`. Also ensure that they are added to the scope being used to test, eg `profile`.

**ISSUING CUSTOM CLAIMS**

You may also want to use claims outside the SCIM schema, which are stored as attributes against the user account. Such fields can be populated using SCIM API requests. For these you need to use the data source claims provider. I used the following attributes query against a single postgres data source:

```sql
SELECT attributes as data FROM accounts WHERE username = :subject
```

I saved a custom field using SCIM and could then issue it as a claim using this configuration:

[image]

In this example I used a custom transformation and, since I am working with raw data, I must call `JSON.parse`:

```js
function transform(attributes) {
  var data = JSON.parse(attributes["data"]);
  return data.customerId;
}
```

**TRANSFORMATIONS**

The JavaScript code you can use in transformations is limited to ECMAScript 5.1, since the Nashorn engine is used. You can read [this tutorial](https://curity.io/resources/learn/getting-started-scripting/) to learn more about how it works.

Comment: thank you for your time, but it doesn't really answer my question. AFAIK, Community version mean 1 DS, so other claims value provider isn't possible.

Comment: Thanks for precision on ECMAScript 5.1. In the accounts table, most of thé SCIM Core user's attributes are in the attributes column in JSON string and not as dedicated columns inside thé accounts table. So according to your 2nd paragraph does it mean that contained attributes from core user SCIM attributes are automatically parsed from 'attributes' column and bind as Builtin OIDC claims ?

Comment: Multiple claims value providers should be fine with a single data source, eg postgres. Is that not the case?

Comment: AFAIK there is only one Attributes query by DS, so I have one Claim Value Provider (CVP) for SCIM repo as account-manager claims provider and another one as data-source-claim-provider. 
By the way my two questions apply to Curity Community version and are : 
1) Why the claim test fail with account-manager based on native SCIM config for attributes like roles, externalId, userType as they respect SCIM COre user schema
- Is there any way to parse the attributes column containing all SCIM Core User schema value one time and not one time for each claim to avoid creating a nested claims bag

Comment: I think you are trying to use the account manager claims provider for claims it does not support. The data source claims provider will work better since it handles any custom claim. You must use JSON.parse for such values, which is a one-liner and a fast operation. I updated my answer - if you follow what I have said there you will be able to issue any claim you need.

Comment: hi, as stated in the description I have tried with userName claim and it doesn't work, name claim works, as email. But both fields even if they are column of thé accounts table aren't SCIM Core user schema native fields. You say native SCIm schema attributes work by design without transformation based on the account-manager-claim-provider but they doesn't bind on my Curity config. That's the problem that make me submit this post. Are externalId & userType unsupported fields even so thete are native attributes of SCIM User schema ?

Comment: I finally got some time to look into this in more depth, and fleshed out the answer with some examples. As you can see, the account manager claims provider supports the SCIM fields you want to issue as claims.

Comment: thank you so much to have taken some time to update your answer. It's now exactly the answer I was looking for. I'ts crystal clear now. you made my day